# Black rectangle in place of pictures on a Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am having some troubles with my chromebook which not displays a lots of pictures, on websites but also in other apps, like the picture gallery.

Is it a known problem? How to repair that?

[image]

Comment: sorry if the sreenshot is not perfect, I was quite blind to make it !

Answer (score 0):

I reset my installation, with this help: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084

and no more problems !